# Permission problems with LinuxDeploy

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, linux, permissions, mount

I installed LinuxDeploy and got Debian Jessie up and running. It was all relatively easy.

The issue that I am having is that the user I define in the ui is not able to write to custom mounts (like sd card etc).

I can use the Root user in the chroot environment to read/write but that is not right. I want to be able to be a regular user with read/write permissions.

I am using Lollipop 5.1/LinuxDeploy on Samsung Note

thanks

Comment: I think this is a software issue with KitKat upwards .. The External SD permission has to be specifically accepted because of the Developer Options " Protect External Storage "      ...... ....... ...... ..... I would suggest you download a SD Card Permission Fixer.. This will patch the security issue to allow external writing and reading......... On the other hand, the internal storage should still be accessible by any app, Unless you have 5.0 and above, This requires accepting the permission with ( Show SD Card ) .. You might be able to add an error exception to run the Show SD Card script

Comment: well, the normal user cant write to any of the memory. I already did the sd card permission fixer things., None worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Confirmed that permissions of /dev/fuse probably just needs to be updated.  It is initially set to 700 by default for some reason which would only allow root to execute. It doesn't matter from where or how you chmod it, just chmod it to 770 or 777 if necessary.

`sudo chmod 777 /dev/fuse`

Also doesn't hurt to do it properly and [setup a fuse group](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/) if one doesn't already exist and add users to it as needed.

**/Update**

Was having a similar problem, will document what I did exactly.  This is assuming you've setup your install as a directory.

1. Download FX File Manager + it's root extension companion app from Play Store.
2. Navigate using the root explorer option to the roots of your Debian install(by default /data/user/linux deploy.package.name.or.similar/0/env
3. Find /dev/fuse of your Debian install with FX.  Long press on the folder, swipe over to / tap security.
4. Tap all the squares so /dev/fuse is set to 777 access
5. Stop and start your image, try accessing mounted directories.

Now I suppose you could try simply chmodding /dev/fuse to 777 from within Debian or whatever access you deem necessary, but I didn't try that.  Most likely that will work too -intuitively sounds fine, but not what I did.

It was.kind of odd that /dev/fuse was set to 700 in the first place, but whatever.

Oh also, I had to add in a fuse group prior to that, and add users to it.  All though my guess is that if you set /dev/fuse to 777 it would make this step unnecessary.  Perhaps a 770 would necessitate the fuse group?

Answer (score 0):

try this fix: https://winaero.com/blog/unlock-external-sd-card-writing-for-all-apps-in-android-4-4-kitkat/
I tried this on Termux and it allow me to write to usb in the termux default user.
It may also work with Linux Deploy. Please reply me with the result